# The SOAP requests I am sending to the queue are becoming malformed on IBM MQ

Tags: java, xml, soap, ibm-mq

I've created a utility in Java which picks up XML files, sends them over to a queue on IBM MQ. When I go into IBM MQ Explorer, the message is showing as received, but there is an ASCII character in front if it (as shown in the "Message Data" field in the image below) which is resulting in it not being recognized as a properly formatted SOAP message which the queue can process. I have tried using XML editors to make sure that my XML files don't have any non-white space characters, but that hasn't resolved the issue.

[image]

Here is my code which I am using to put the file on the queue:

```
 * sending message to MQ
 * 
 * @param file
 * @return messageId
 * @throws UnsupportedEncodingException
 * @throws IOException
 */
private byte[] sendMessageToMQ(File file) throws UnsupportedEncodingException, IOException {

    int openOptions = MQC.MQOO_INPUT_AS_Q_DEF | MQC.MQOO_OUTPUT;
    try {
        defaultLocalQueue = qManager.accessQueue(queueName, openOptions);

        MQMessage putMessage = new MQMessage();

        String msg = readFile(file);
        putMessage.writeUTF(msg);

        // specify the message options...
        MQPutMessageOptions pmo = new MQPutMessageOptions();
        // accept
        // put the message on the queue
        defaultLocalQueue.put(putMessage, pmo);

        System.out.println("Message is put on MQ.");

        return putMessage.messageId;

    } catch (MQException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Sounds like an encoding issue.  Should be XML encoded UTF-8.   I wonder what a queue is buying you here.  Why not just send the SOAP request to a web service?

Comment: How do you read the files and transform them into messages?

Comment: @duffymo we are trying to test if the queues are doing their job properly, which is to generate a response and send it back. I'm reliant on queues because the entire operation is built that way, and as a new developer, I have to work with existing technology.

Comment: It's a poor design, in my view.  Sorry.

Comment: Can you post the part of the code that is putting the message?

Comment: @Shashi Done :) See above.

Comment: MQ code is fine, don't see anything wrong. Can you check the file contents? There could be some additional characters in the file. You could print the file contents before calling message.writeUTF() and compare with message content after the put call.

Comment: I used a fancy XML editor (Oxygen XML) to make sure there weren't any aberrations within it... it's quite a mystery why this is happening..

Comment: MQExplorer might be showing that way. But it's always best to get the message form queue and compare the message body of the received message with file contents. Jason has rightly pointed out the reason for additional characters.

Answer (score 4):

writeUTF is documented as prefixing the data with the length

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_9.0.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q030840_.htm

> Note: The writeUTF() method of MQMessage automatically encodes the
>   length of the string as well as the Unicode bytes it contains. When
>   your message will be read by another Java program (using readUTF()),
>   this is the simplest way to send string information.

You can set the characterSet of the MQMessage to 1208 (or whatever the ccsid of the message is currently according to the explorer), then use the writeString method

https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=77777777-0000-0000-0000-000000023465

> If you need UTF-8 text in your message, but don't require the two byte
>   length field, set the characterSet field to 1208 (which is the CCSID
>   for  UTF-8) and use writeString().

Note although this article talks about .net, but the same is true for Java:
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21267940